# How to get values from child nodes using java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I have a XML content like below...

```
<Parent_Tag>
          <Parent_Tag_1>
            <Component>
              <Type>ABC</Type>
              <Amount>
                <Value_1>0.1</Value_1>
                <Value_2>AAA</Value_2>
              </Amount>
            </Component>
          </Parent_Tag_1>
          <Parent_Tag_2>
            <Item>
              <Item_1>
                <Component>
                  <Type>CCC</Type>
                  <Amount>
                    <Value_1>0.1</Value_1>
                    <Value_2>BB</Value_2>
                  </Amount>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                  <Type>BBB</Type>
                  <Amount>
                    <Value_1>2.0</Value_1>
                    <Value_2>AA</Value_2>
                  </Amount>
                </Component>
              </Item_1>             
            </Item>
          </Parent_Tag_2>       
        </Parent_Tag>
```

I need to get the values in **tag Component** under Parent_Tag_1. But my code gave all the component tags under **Parent_Tag**. How to fix this ??

Please give a suggestion...

Comment: Could you post your code so that we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Jia jian Thank you for your comment.. I found the mistake what I did wrong. I was put the wrong element in code(i.e) Element of Parent_Tag node not a Parent_Tag_1.

Comment: @JayVenkat do you want to post your answer and accept it, in case anybody with the same question can find it?

Comment: @Jia Jian I think.. no need of that.. I made a mistake in my code like I denoted a wrong element in function. It doesn't share any info to others..         Thanks Jia for your valuable comments.. :)